# Getting JSON response into String in Java?

Tags: java, json, http

I am getting responses in JSON format when I make API requests to an api.

I am getting this when I do the `System.Out.Println` of the response.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK [Date: Thu, 04 Oct 2012 20:33:18 GMT, Server: Apache/1.3.33 (Unix) PHP/4.4.0, Cache-control: no-cache, must-revalidate, no-cache="Set-Cookie", private, Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT, Pragma: no-cache, X-CreationTime: 0.051, Set-Cookie: DT=1349382798:29998:365-l4; path=/; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2020 00:00:00 GMT; domain=.wunderground.com, Connection: close, Transfer-Encoding: chunked, Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8]
```

But it is not the expected response, the response should be like this,

```
response: {
name:
class:
}
```

I am using Apache HTTP Client.

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url); 
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
System.out.println(response);
```

What should I do next in order to get the expected result? I just need a point in right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to do something like this instead:

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(response.getEntity().getContent()); 
String line;     
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) { 
    sb.append(line);
} 
in.close(); 
String json = sb.toString();
```

Comment: For reference, it would be much more efficient to use a `CharBuffer` with `InputStream.read(CharBuffer)` instead of the series of `String` objects returned by `BufferedInputStream.getLine()`. It saves on both memory allocation and searching for line breaks.

Answer (score 3):

I am answering my own question here:

After a little bit of more research on Apache website, I found this:

```
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
```

Believe me it is lot more easier and works like a charm.