# Extracting Data from a JSON response in Java?

Tags: java, json, jackson

This question follows from my own question here,

[Getting JSON response into String in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12735545/getting-json-response-into-string-in-java/12736397#12736397)

Well, I did get the expected result. Now If I want to extract the specific part of JSON response and use it to say, save it in a database, how would I do that?

I am thinking of using Jackson JSON parser. I checked the tutorials, but it is using only a file not a HTTP request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jackson is an excellent choice.  I don't know what you gleaned from the tutorials; you might have to read beyond them.  Jackson is a good Java library for manipulating JSON.

Comment: They are just using a file. Not a HTTP response.

Comment: File is just a source.  Replace that bit with the value from HTTP and figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

[`Gson`](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) is an excellent json parser. You can use that to convert json [to Java objects](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Object-Examples).

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Foo foo = gson.fromJson("{your json string}", Foo.class);
```

If you're uncertain on what the `Foo` class should look like you can always create `Foo` as how you think it should look and serialize that to compare against your json string.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
gson.toJson(new Foo());
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonStreamingApi) is what you're looking for. Note in the comment it says `// or URL, Stream, Reader, String, byte[]` meaning that any form of input stream could be used. Just get the input stream from the HTTP connection you're using and parse away.\

Actually same sort of thing can be done with the tutorial you might have read as well (with object mapping). The methods for reading the JSON stream, be it String, InputStream, or whatever, are overloaded to take multiple inputs and map them to a corresponding object.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass a Byte instead of a file.
Check out the Jackson [API](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.8.8/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.html)

Can you get the parameter(s) from the request and turn them into byte arrays?

```
String source = "" +request.getParameter("param1");
byte[] byteArray = source.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposed JSON is a simple plain object and readable with a string. Just convert the inputstream to a plain string in a correct chart set, then you could parse the string with Jackson mapper i think.

getMapper().readValue(dataStr, Class.class);

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your entire response is a json and not only part of it.

You could try Genson http://code.google.com/p/genson/. It has most of jackson features plus other ones that are quite usefull, Genson is also easier to use and tries to be more open to extension than jackson.
Here is a solution where you will use the databinding capabilities of Genson to deserialize your stream into a java object and then you would work with your object and do whatever you want.

```
InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
Genson genson = new Genson();
ObjectReader reader = genson.createReader(instream);
DeserializeIntoThisClass myObject = genson.deserialize(DeserializeIntoThisClass.class, reader, new Context(genson));
// and now you can work with this object and store it in a database if you want
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `URL` instead of `File`, which you could find from Javadocs, so:

```
MyObject ob = new ObjectMapper().readValue(url, MyObject.class);
```